# Can a local field be local in more than one way?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, local-field

A local field (to my knowledge) is a field equipped with a non-trivial absolute value that makes it a locally compact topological space. From this, one derives that the local fields are $\Bbb R,\Bbb C,$ finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p,$ and $\Bbb F_q((x))$ with the usual absolute values/valuations.

If $K$ is a local field with respect to some absolute value $|\cdot|$, can there be a further, non-equivalent absolute value on $K$ making it again local? I have the strong suspicion that the answer is "no", but would like to know precisely how this can be proved.

Comment: @ChadK I'm not asking why every local field is topologically isomorphic to one of the fields listed, my question is about how they relate to one another. E.g. why can't $\Bbb R$ be a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$, why a finite extension of $\Bbb Q_p$ can't also be an extension of $\Bbb Q_q$, why $\Bbb Q_p$ isn't isomorphic to $\Bbb R$, and so on -- admittedly some of these are trivial (e.g. $\Bbb Q_p$ can't be topologically isomorphic to $\Bbb R$ because one is connected while the other is totally disconnected), but you get the idea. Perhaps this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 1):

A field that is complete with respect to two non-equivalent absolute values is separably closed. So if $K\ne \Bbb C$, the answer to your question is no. For $K=\Bbb C$, one can also take other absolute values: Take an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\Bbb C$ which is not the identity or complex conjugation. Then $\lVert x\rVert:=|\sigma(x)|$ defines another absolute value of $\Bbb C$ for which $\Bbb C$ is again a local field (as it will be isomorphic to the usual $\Bbb C$ via $\sigma$).

The idea of the proof of the first statement is roughly the following: Take an irreducible separable polynomial $g$ over $K$. There is a polynomial $h$ of the same degree that splits completely over $K$. Then using the approximation theorem choose a polynomial $f$ (of the same degree) which is very close to $g$ w.r.t. to the first absolute value and very close to $h$ w.r.t. the other. Applying Krasner's lemma for both absolute values then shows that $f$ must be both irreducible and split completely over $K$, which forces $\deg g=\deg f=1$, so $K$ is separably closed.

Comment: But to apply Krasner's lemma (at least the version that is familiar to me) to $h$ it needs to be irreducible and separable, which would imply $\deg h=1$, since $h$ splits over $K$ by assumption. And what you say doesn't seem to use the non-equivalence of the absolute values, since the same could be done to $|\cdot|$ and $|\cdot|^s$.

Comment: You can first use Krasner's lemma to to deduce that $f$ is irreducible. Check out Proposition 7.61 in [Milne's ANT notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ANT.pdf). We do need that the absolute values are inequivalent to get the polynomial $f$ (approximation theorem)

Comment: Also I should mention that this statement only applies to non-archimedean absolute values

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked on MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433920/field-complete-with-respect-to-inequivalent-absolute-values/433926#433926), with "locally compact" replaced by "complete". My answer there deals with the case where the field is locally compact, showing in this case that the absolute value is determined up to equivalence by the field structure.